# How to copy a file to clipboard in python

Tags: python, clipboard, copy-paste, file-copying

Like normally, we can copy files directly to clipboard by simply
`ctrl + c`

But I want to do that using python

```
path = "..."
def copy_file_to_clipboard() -> None: 
   clipboard.copy_file(path) # this is a false code, but I want to know the code to do so
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How copy file to clipboard using python or CL to paste it using STRG+V later on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234123/how-copy-file-to-clipboard-using-python-or-cl-to-paste-it-using-strgv-later-on)

Comment: Windows, Linux, both? Other?

Answer (score 1):

To simulate right click copy action on file Windows:

```
import os
path = 'C:\folder\text.txt'
command = f"powershell Set-Clipboard -LiteralPath {path}"
os.system(command)
```

Comment: This solution actually works, I tried it for copying a GIF to the clipboard. you need to have Powershell installed.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution tested in python 3.9 (Notebook jupyter) :

```
import pyperclip as pc
def copy_to_clipboard(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
        pc.copy(text)
        print("File successfully copied to clipboard!")
copy_to_clipboard('file.txt')
```

Comment: This only copies the content of the file